# Why the closed unit ball is the countable union of disjoint cells?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, lebesgue-measure

I'm studing measure in the Bartle's book and his coments that the closed disk:

$$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | x^2+y^2\leq 1 \}$$

Is the countable union of disjoint cell's (intervals in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

But i'm dont understand why this not contradicts the connected of the disk , because if $$D=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I_n$$

Then i can write $$D= I_k\cup \bigcup_{n\neq k} I_n$$, and this sets they are disjoints , not empty and your union is D , so D have an not trivial cut.

Comment: You haven't said what type of interval. Open? Closed? Half-open-half-closed?